# Read each node in IEnumerable<XElement> using XMlReader

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xmlreader, xelement, system.xml

I have `IEnumerable<XElement> theTestCaseNodes` which has the following kind of XElements

```
<testcase>
    <Main>  
       <test_step type ="action">
           <Name>Goto</Name>
           <description>xxxxxxxxx</description>    
       </test_step>  
       <test_step type ="check">
           <Name>Click</Name>
           <description>xxxxxxxxx</description>
       </test_step>  
    </Main>  
</testcase>
<testcase>
    <Main>  
       <test_step type ="action">
           <Name>Goto</Name>
           <description>xxxxxxxxx</description>    
       </test_step>  
       <test_step type ="check">
           <Name>Type</Name>
           <description>xxxxxxxxx</description>
       </test_step>  
    </Main>  
</testcase>
```

Basically this is my testcase and I want to execute them in an order.
So, now I want to read each node in IEnumerable using XMLReader.

Please help how to proceed!!

I understood that i need to use "using" but not sure how to proceed.

```
public void ExecuteTestcase(IEnumerable<XElement> theTestCaseNodes)
{
    using (XmlReader aNodeReader = XmlReader.ReadSubtree()) {

    }
}
```

Comment: You could write your xml to a string, create a `StringReader` on that and pass it to the `XmlReader`.  Note you have to `Create` a reader in the `using` then you can call instance methods like `ReadSubtree`.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to use XmlReader? That is used to convert text to DOM, but you already have DOM level elements.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Please let me know more about this. I'am new to XML.I want to use XMLReader here because I want to go in order. There are 2types of steps, "type=Action" and "type=check" and I want to read them in order.

Comment: The whole idea of order is a bit tricky in XML but `xElement.Elements("test_step")` should give you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `XElement.CreateReader` for instantiating `XmlReader` for the element.

```
public void ExecuteTestcase(IEnumerable<XElement> theTestCaseNodes)
{
    foreach(var node in theTestCaseNodes)
    {
        using (var reader = node.CreateReader())
        {
            // use XmlReader for testing
        }
    }
}
```

[XNode.CreateReader Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299560(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

If main purpose of `XmlReader` is reading elements in correct order then looping through elements will execute them in same order they appear in xml

```
foreach(var testStep in theTestCaseNodes.Elements("test_step"))
{
    // execute step
}
```

If you don't want rely on order of your xml then you can access correct step by `type` attribute

```
foreach(var testStep in theTestCaseNodes.Elements("Main"))
{
    var action = testStep.Elements("test_step")
                         .First(step => step.Attribute("type") == "action");
    var check = testStep.Elements("test_step")
                        .First(step => step.Attribute("type") == "action");

    // execute action
    // execute check
}
```